# How to filter two lists in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two `List<CustomObject>` and I want to create **filtered list** which will contain only items from **second list**, which are **not present** in **first list**. Parameter for comparison is `objectId` which is unique `String` value.

Comment: Are the items inside the `List<CustomObject>` are unique

Comment: Yes, its ParseObject. Just to be exact

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, get the IDs of the first list:

```
val firstListIds = firstList.map { it.objectId }.
```

Then, filter the second list by checking if the ID is among the IDs of the first list:

```
val result = secondList.filter { it.objectId !in firstListIds }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the following might work well:

```
val firstListObjectIds = firstList.map { it.objectId }.toSet()
val filteredList = secondList.filter { !firstListObjectIds.contains(it.objectId) }
```

Comment: `!xxx.contains(yyy)` could be shortened to `xxx !in yyy`. Anyhow, I believe this solution is better as `contains` is generally faster for `Set`s than for `List`s. It will also use less memory if there are many duplicate entries